# Users are always logged out on front end

Tags: frontend, login, current-user

Users are always logged out on the front end on my Craft website.  Even when logged in as admin I can access the CMS but on the front end user session always returns the following.

```
Craft\UserSessionService Object
(
    [_identity:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [_identityCookie:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [_userModel:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [_userRow:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [_sessionRestoredFromCookie:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [_dontExtendSession:Craft\UserSessionService:private] => 
    [allowAutoLogin] => 1
    [guestName] => Guest
    [loginUrl] => Array
        (
            [0] => /site/login
        )

    [identityCookie] => 
    [authTimeout] => 259200
    [absoluteAuthTimeout] => 
    [autoRenewCookie] => 1
    [autoUpdateFlash] => 1
    [loginRequiredAjaxResponse] => 
    [_keyPrefix:CWebUser:private] => 4e3924125ff89a395a13e8e5580209e2
    [_access:CWebUser:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [behaviors] => Array
        (
        )

    [_initialized:CApplicationComponent:private] => 1
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Is the Control Panel on a different domain/subdomain than the front-end of your site?

Comment: No its the same domain for CP and front-end.

Comment: Weird... maybe something in @khalwat's answer helps?

Answer (score 4):

I tracked down a similar problem, and documented it here: [The Case of the Missing PHP Session](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session)

I'm not sure if it'll address the issue you're having specifically, but it may give you some clue on where to look.